# Do we ever see what Geordi La Forge sees?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Terminator 2, we get few shots from the Terminator's perspective, mostly technical read-outs and a red filter.  Do we get anything similar for Geordi La Forge's VISOR?

I don't know much about Star Trek, I don't mean to exclude any works by using only the TNG tag.  If it happens in another work, I'd still like to know.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you asked about *Geordi's POV*, so Valorum's answer is correct. However, looking at just your *summary*, no we don't (and *can't*) "see what Geordi La Forge sees", because he "sees" a *lot* more of the spectrum than we can.

Comment: @Matthew That's an interesting point.

Comment: Well, we could simplify to "observe what Geordi is able to **perceive** , i.e. resolution and contrast in the scene.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### We see from Geordi's POV on several occasions.

---

In the episode *[TNG: Heart of Glory](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Heart_of_Glory_(episode))* when he uses a "[Visual Acuity Transmitter](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Visual_acuity_transmitter)"

---

In the episode *[TNG: The Mind's Eye](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mind%27s_Eye_(episode))*, albeit his vision has been tampered with by the Romulans.

---

In the episode [*TNG: The Enemy*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Enemy_(episode)), noting that his 'neural interface' with the VISOR is being interfered with by electromagnetic something or other.

[image]

---

The Klingons also see from Geordi's perspective in the film *[Star Trek Generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations)*, but they've isolated only the visual spectra, which means that although we're seeing from his point-of-view, we're not seeing what he would normally see.

Comment: There are also some VISOR-eye views in S3E7, "The Enemy", where Geordi is stranded on a desolate planet with a Romulan--first is a little under 8 minutes in where Geordi is looking at some minerals in a wall, next is a little under 18 minutes in where he's seeing a neutrino beam from a probe sent down by the Enterprise as a beacon.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I was going to add that one, but I've been struggling to find a suitable video. I've had to settle for making a gif

Comment: Bear in mind that these shown images and videos are the VERY POOR 2d, rgb, low-resolution rendition that we mere mortals have available to display the multichannel datastream of unspecified but very high resolution that Geordi gets all the time. Remember that he is capable of seeing a microscopic crack in a plasma conduit from more than 2 meters away!

Comment: Ahhh! Geordi LaForge, the 25th Century's Poster Child for Insurmountable Information Overload

Comment: The very concept of this is problematic. Geordi's sensory environment is very different from other humans. It reminds me of the philosophical paper [*What is it like to be a bat?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_It_Like_to_Be_a_Bat%3F)

Comment: You forgot First Contact. The scene where they're trying to find where Cochrane has run off to